# Delegate is never executed while invoked via Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with ContextIdle priority

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, begininvoke

I work on a WPF application.
I have the following code:

[image]

But I never get to the breakpoint that is put at the beginning of ExpandFreeDraw method:

[image]

When I invoke the BeginInvoke method, I'm already on the UI thread:

[image]

The ExpandFreeDraw method should also happen on the UI Thread. 
I invoke it with priority of context idle for the following reason:

Before the line of BeginInvoke, I change the Visibility of a WPF Expander from collapsed to Visible. It starts rendering its controls: some of those controls are input controls and I want to apply validation to them (done via AdornerDecorator which makes it look like the input control has a red validation border). 
If I call the ExpandFreeDraw directly after changing the visibility of the Expander (just ExpandFreeDraw() without Dispatcher), I do get to the breakpoint at the beginning of the ExpandFreeDraw method: the expander is visible but the adorner is not applied correctly - no red border effect.

I get the same effect with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with the next lower priority, which is background:

[image]

In that case, I also get to the breakpoint at the beginning of the ExpandFreeDraw method.
When I apply the next priority, which is ContextIdle, then my issue is reproduced - I don't get to the mentioned breakpoint.

Note that this functionality works most of the time, and that's how I know the ContextIdle priority is my desired priority, because it does apply the validation to input controls in most of the cases (if I reduce the priority to Background, it already doesn't). That is because the priority given to the Dispatcher is ContextIdle which is lesser that Render - You can read more about it here: http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/08/29/update-my-ui-now-how-to-wait-for-the-rendering-to-finish/).

I would like to get some help on how to figure out what is the problem. Why is

[image]

invokes the method of ExpandFreeDraw correctly in most of the cases, but in one of the scenarios (which I can't really understand which) it doesn't?
How can I debug it?

Maybe:

[image]

Could it be that the background operations are never completed? And that's why the operation with ContextIdle priority is never executed? How can I figure it out?

Comment: Please, share the code sample, rather then images

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Please post [**M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Have you tried to break/pause the application and see if some of background threads is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved it.
My issue was that the UI dispatcher queue kept constantly getting actions with a higher priority (higher than context-idle).

If you write a code as the following:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => DoBackGround1()), DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Debug.WriteLine("Context-Idle")), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Debug.WriteLine("Additional-Background")), DispatcherPriority.Background, null);



        });
        t.Name = "dispatcherTest";
        t.Start();
    }


    private void DoBackGround1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Debug.WriteLine("Background " + i);
        }
    }
```

You will get the following result in the output window:

Background 0 
Background 1 
Background 2
Background 3
Background 4
Background 5
Background 6
Background 7
Background 8
Background 9
Additional-Background
Context-Idle

Additional-Background action is performed before the context-idle action, even though it was queued into the UI queue dispatcher after the context-idle action. It's trivial, but it is important to understand this concept.

I had a code that checks if I'm on the UI thread - If so, perform the action immediately. Otherwise, queue it into the dispatcher queue. When I forced the mentioned action (ExpandFreeDraw) into the UI queue (even if I was already on the UI thread), it all worked for me: now the action is invoked and I also get the needed validation.